# Disabling pagefile (Windows 8.1) causes system crash on boot

Tags: windows, boot, shutdown, hibernate, pagefile

Actually... it's way worse than a simple crash - it's more like the machine suddenly loses *all* power and is shut down forcibly. I get not further than the boot logo and the machine just kinda dies.

I have fast-startup and hibernation enabled and the problem only occurs in these two cases.

Rebooting it seems to work (maybe because it's not using the kernel hibernation file anymore). Re-enabling the pagefile also fixes the problem.

The problem isn't there with a totally fresh and untainted installation, but kinda creeps in after I install some drivers (not sure which one causes it).

BTW I know a lot of people say there is no reason to disable the pagefile (especially with 8/16 GB RAM these days). But this increases my computer's performance *massively*, by reducing hard drive access (as task manager suggests). My system seems to use the pagefile too often and too unnecessarily (even when RAM is like 40% full).

Comment: with ProcessHacker you can see under tools->pagefiles the usage: http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/ How much is used that is too much for you?

Comment: @magicandre1981 by too much I mean too often, and for no apparent reason (when using only a few chrome tabs or something)

Comment: Chrome is RAM waster. Use a better browser ;)

Comment: @magicandre1981 haha very funny (true though). i just like google's stuff